# How to create full width content in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

If you are familiar with wordpress there is usually a sidebar that takes up a portion and the main content which takes the other.  My question is how I would go about creating full-page content after both that disregards each while still keeping the sidebar (and main content) intact.  I would think that at the very least I'd need to calculate the sidebar height and maybe main content height to make sure the content comes after... not sure what css would like though.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the main content with sidebar in one DIV, then just make a 2nd DIV after that one which wraps your full-page content.

Comment: Perhaps mark the question as solved and post how you solved it, in case that helps another user with the same question!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it for anyone.  Every theme is pretty much the same, I just inserted my full width content within the main tag after the sidebar, within theme-footer.php

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
 </div> <!-- .row -->
<?php echo do_shortcode('[some-full-width-function]'); ?>
</div> <!-- #main -->
</div> <!-- #page -->
```